# Countdown Time Javascript Automatically reset and Server Time Issue

Tags: javascript, timer, reset, countdown, business-catalyst

We are having an issue setting up a countdown timer to automatically reset itself after a couple of hours. Also we need to set up the timer so that it is not based on the clients local time. We are hosting the site on Business Catalyst which doesn't except server side languages so I would need to use strictly javascript to lock in a server time. Here is the countdown timer we are currently using for the website.

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/

As far as the automatically reset issue we are having I figure that we can set a loop schedule variable using later.js

http://bunkat.github.io/later/

I've set up the variable I just don't know how to add the reset function to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var sched = later.parse.text('on the first day of the week at ');
      t = later.setInterval(test, sched),
      count = 5;

  function test() {
    console.log(new Date());
    count--;
    if(count <= 0) {
      t.clear();
    }
  }


</script>
```

```
function reset() {
    $('#countdown_dashboard').stopCountDown();
    $('#countdown_dashboard').setCountDown({
    targetOffset: {
    'day':      7,
    'month':    0,
    'year':     0,
    'hour':     9,
    'min':      0,
    'sec':      0
    }
    });            
    $('#countdown_dashboard').startCountDown();
}
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
            targetDate: {
                'day':      15,
                'month':    6,
                'year':     2014,
                'hour':     11,
                'min':      10,
                'sec':      0
            },
            // onComplete function
            onComplete: function() { 
                $('#complete_info_message').slideDown(), 
                $('#countdown_dashboard').addClass('ended');
            },
            omitWeeks: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

I think using later.js we can set the countdown using a targetOffset so that the compleate message fires off after week or somehow add 7 days in the targetDate "day" area without it putting a weird data like 40.